# Where is segment %fs for static elf images setup?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, glibc, elf

I'm trying to figure out how the %fs register is initialized 
when creating a elf image by hand.

The simple snippet I'd like to run is:

```
        .text
        nop
        movq %fs:0x28, %rax;
1:      jmp 1b
```

Which should read at offset 0x28 in the %fs segment. Normally this is where the stack canary is stored. Because I create the elf image by hand the %fs segment is not setup at all by my code this fails expectedly(?) .

Here is how I create the elf image:

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   90                      nop
   1:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   8:   00 00 
   a:   eb fe                   jmp    0xa
```

I create the .text segment via

```
echo 9064488b042528000000ebfe | xxd -r -p > r2.bin
```

Then I convert to elf:

```
ld -b binary -r -o raw.elf r2.bin
objcopy  --rename-section .data=.text --set-section-flags .data=alloc,code,load raw.elf
```

At that point `raw.elf` contains my instructions. I then link with
`ld -T raw.ld -o out.elf -M --verbose` where raw.ld is:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_entry)
PHDRS {
phdr4000000 PT_LOAD;
}
SECTIONS
{
  _entry = 0x4000000;
  .text 0x4000000 : { raw.elf (.text) } :phdr4000000
}
```

I can now start out.elf with gdb:

```
gdb --args out.elf
```

and set a breakpoint at 0x4000000:

```
(gdb)break *0x4000000
(gdb)run
```

The first `nop` can be stepped via `stepi`, however the stack canary read `mov    %fs:0x28,%rax` segfaults.

I suppose that is expected given that maybe the OS is not setting up %fs. 
For a simple m.c: `int main() { return 0; }` program compiled with `gcc --static m.c -o m` I can read from %fs. Adding:

```
long can()
{
        long v = 0;
        __asm__("movq %%fs:0x28, %0;"
                : "=r"(val)::);
        return v;
}
```

lets me read from %fs - even though I doubt that %fs:28 is setup because ld.so is not run (it is a static image).

Question:

Can anyone point out where %fs is setup in the c runtime for *static* images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`arch_prctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/arch_prctl.2.html) with an `ARCH_SET_FS` argument before you can use the `%fs` segment prefix.  You will have to allocate the backing store somewhere (`brk`, `mmap`, or an otherwise unused part of the stack).

glibc does this in `__libc_setup_tls` in `csu/libc-tls.c` for statically linked binaries, hidden behind the `TLS_INIT_TP` macro.